# Why is the sort not working (subscription issue?)

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor, iron-router

I wanted to add an additional sort by distance function to the Microscope app.

Problem is the list is still not sorted, still throws me the full list. Server wise, no errors thrown out so I guess the publish is working fine. The only server error is upon starting up the server and is as below:

> Exception from sub postsByDistance id KcEizuxZWk3ifm6A9 Error:
>   Exception while polling query
>   {"collectionName":"posts","selector":{"location":{"$near":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[null,null]},"$maxDistance":500}}},"options":{"transform":null}}:
>   $near requires a point, given { type: "Point", coordinates: [ null,
>   null ] }

Theres no errors displayed on the front-end. The console log for position appears with the correct position.

Which parts are bad or perhaps advice how do I check for errors/ troubleshoot? especially for the client/ front end console checks etc.

Microscope has 2 sort functions lumped into one router, as shown below:

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'postsList',
  increment: 5, 
  postsLimit: function() { 
    return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment; 
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return { 
      sort: this.sort, 
      limit: this.postsLimit() };
  },
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
  },
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
  },
  postsByDistance: function() {   // suggested by Brian, still doesnt work
    return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
  },
  data: function() {
    var self = this;
    return { 
      posts: self.posts(), 
      ready: self.postsSub.ready,
      nextPath: function() {
        if (self.posts().count() === self.postsLimit())
          return self.nextPath();
      }
    };
  }
});

NewPostsController = PostsListController.extend({
  sort: {submitted: -1},  
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.newPosts.path({ postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment }) 
  }
});
BestPostsController = PostsListController.extend({
  sort: {votes: -1},           
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.bestPosts.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment})
  }
});
// What I have inserted
NearPostsController = PostsListController.extend({
  sort: {postsByDistance: -1},    // removing this throws "no sort key" error
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.nearPosts.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment})
  }
});

Router.route('/', { name: 'home', controller: NewPostsController }); 
Router.route('/new/:postsLimit?',   { name: 'newPosts'} );
Router.route('/best/:postsLimit?',  { name: 'bestPosts'} );
Router.route('/near/:postsLimit?',  { name: 'nearPosts'} );  // What I inserted
```

**The server js**

```
Posts._ensureIndex({'location' : '2dsphere'});  
  Meteor.publish('postsByDistance', function(location) {                                
  return Posts.find({
    location: { 
      $near: { $geometry: {type:"Point", coordinates: [location.lng, location.lat]
        }, $maxDistance: 500 ......etc etc
```

**The subscription in client (shared by new, best posts but their codes are all on router)**

```
  Meteor.subscribe("postsByDistance", location);

  posts: function() { return Posts.find(); }  //under helper... I tried to add sort here but doesnt work
```

Comment: You should be using the `$near` query operator, but I don't see it in your query. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: Have you added the 2dsphere index to the collection?

Comment: Yes I have that too. let me paste the entire lines. Sorry about that! :)

Comment: It looks like the `NearPostsController` is passing a `sort` option to the `PostsListController`. Since the `$near` command should already sort the documents by distance you just need to remove the `sort` option in that controller. In your `PostsListController` you also need to check to see if the sort option is missing and not add it to the `findOptions` object before returning it.

Comment: Also, from what you've pasted here, it doesn't look you're ever calling the `postsByDistance` subscription. You only have the `posts` subscription in your `PostsListController`.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Removing sort (`NearPostsController`) throws server side error: Exception from sub posts id xx Error: Match error: Missing key 'sort'. How would you check for a missing sort option? (using If statements?). The subscription is template level (last code, under client js). Also added `postsByDistance` call in `PostsListController`. Not working yet.